# Formview.Updateitem Gives Error "Input string not in correct format". However Formview Update works

Tags: asp.net

This is the subroutine which calls the Update Item method. The button is on the edit template. It calls   another subroutine to get a value which is used to update a textbox on the edit template. It then calls updateitem to save that value to the database

```
Protected Sub btnCreateChargerRecord_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)

          Dim MyFormview As FormView = UpdatePanel1.FindControl("Formview1")
          Dim lblChargerSerialNumber As TextBox = MyFormview.FindControl("FL_Charger_Serial_NumberTextBox")
          Dim ddlState As DropDownList = MyFormview.FindControl("ddlState")      

          Session("State") = ddlState.SelectedValue.ToString
          lblChargerSerialNumber.Text = GetBatterySerialNumber(Session("State"), "Charger").ToString
          Try
               MyFormview.UpdateItem(False)

          Catch ex As FormatException
               MessageLabel.Text = ex.Message.ToString & ex.Source.ToString
          End Try

End Sub
```

When I run this code I get an error " Input string not in the correct format"
 However if I comment out the  MyFormview.UpdateItem(False) line and update using the standard formview link button "Update" no error results . See Below for HTML for Formview

Comment: I don't see the Formview HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved. The problem related to a textbox on the Edit Item Template :-

```
<asp:TextBox ID="FL_Battery_PriceTextBox" runat="server" 
            Text='<%# Bind("FL_Battery_Price","{0:$#0.00}") %>'               CssClass="FieldValue" 
            Style="z-index: 135; left: 502px; position: absolute; top: 651px" 
            Width="100px" Height="20px" 
            ></asp:TextBox>
```

which formatted the database value to display it with a leading dollar sign. Breaking in the ItemUpdating event handler and checking the NewValues I saw that the link button Update method had removed the leading $ sign but the UpdateItem method does not thus causing the format error above. so the solution is to manually remove the leading $ sign in the ItemUpdating event